# How to import Blender 3D Model to three.js

Tags: three.js, blender

I tried to import Blender 3D Model to three.js using the three.js Blender Export plugin from the Threejs GitHub Repo but the latter has been removed. Is there another way to do it without using Three.js Blender Export ?
Please provide examples on the other methods.

Comment: I quess you'll find more help on the representing stack exchange site. Maybe close this question and create one on: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are lots of examples and documentation on how to do this on the threejs.org website: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Comment: Just one of many possibilities: Export your project to Collada file format (`.dae`) and then use the ColladaLoader of three.js to import it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the GLTF exporter for blender and the corresponding importer for THREE.js. GLTF is a modern format optimized for Web 3d content delivery.